# Android phone that comes with only essential apps?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a budget android phone that only comes with play store, messages, gallery, phone, contacts, settings and maybe a couple other apps.

Most phones seem to come with unneeded extra apps that take up valuable space on the phone especially on a budget phone.

Edit: I’m looking for phones under $70.

Comment: You can root most android phones and remove all the apps to your hearts' desire.

Comment: @Rubydesic are you recommending a phone because the budget phones tend to be tricky.

Comment: You want a phone under $70 you might as well just buy used

Answer (score 3):

While budget is unspecific, you can get a [Motorola G7 Play](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N9MF1Q3), [unlock the bootloader](https://support.motorola.com/us/en/solution/ms87215), root it, and then remove all the apps you don't want. Currently **$120** on Amazon.

- 32GB Internal Storage
- 2GB RAM
- 5.7" screen
- [More Specs - GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g7_play-9532.php)

[image: 1]

Comment: Note: This helpful answer was likely posted *before* the OP edited the question to specify a lower price constraint.  This recommended phone has good reviews, a good reputation, and a good history going back several generations.